# Declaring and setting variable within select statement sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

So I have a piece of very repetitive code which needs to be minimized because the LMS I am required to use requires max 2000 character input. This 2000 characters is the "CASE" statement, not the "FROM" statement which comes later.

Basically, I have a feedback form that users submit through the LMS, and I want to take that information and build a report from the multiple tables.

Here is the code to get the response:

```
case when 
        (select e.response_value 
        from t_qti_item_evaluation r INNER JOIN t_qti_response e 
            ON r.response_id = e.response_id INNER JOIN t_qti_evaluationflowmaterial f 
            ON f.subitem_id = r.subitem_id INNER JOIN [t_qti_evaluationmaterial] i 
            ON i.flowmaterial_id = f.flowmaterial_id 
                where i.flowmaterial_id = 1385628 
                    and i.position = 1 
                    and r.item_evaluation_id = b.item_evaluation_id) = 1 then 'Highly Satisfied' 
  when 
    (select e.response_value 
        from t_qti_item_evaluation r INNER JOIN t_qti_response e 
            ON r.response_id = e.response_id INNER JOIN t_qti_evaluationflowmaterial f 
            ON f.subitem_id = r.subitem_id INNER JOIN [t_qti_evaluationmaterial] i 
            ON i.flowmaterial_id = f.flowmaterial_id 
                where i.flowmaterial_id = 1385628 
                    and i.position = 1 
                    and r.item_evaluation_id = b.item_evaluation_id) = 2 then 'Satisfied' 
  when 
    (select e.response_value 
        from t_qti_item_evaluation r INNER JOIN t_qti_response e 
            ON r.response_id = e.response_id INNER JOIN t_qti_evaluationflowmaterial f 
            ON f.subitem_id = r.subitem_id INNER JOIN [t_qti_evaluationmaterial] i 
            ON i.flowmaterial_id = f.flowmaterial_id 
                where i.flowmaterial_id = 1385628 
                    and i.position = 1 
                    and r.item_evaluation_id = b.item_evaluation_id) = 3 then 'Disatisfied' 
  when 
    (select e.response_value 
        from t_qti_item_evaluation r INNER JOIN t_qti_response e 
            ON r.response_id = e.response_id INNER JOIN t_qti_evaluationflowmaterial f 
            ON f.subitem_id = r.subitem_id INNER JOIN [t_qti_evaluationmaterial] i 
            ON i.flowmaterial_id = f.flowmaterial_id 
                where i.flowmaterial_id = 1385628 
                    and i.position = 1 
                    and r.item_evaluation_id = b.item_evaluation_id) = 4 then 'Highly Disatisfied' 
  when 
    (select e.response_value 
        from t_qti_item_evaluation r INNER JOIN t_qti_response e 
            ON r.response_id = e.response_id INNER JOIN t_qti_evaluationflowmaterial f 
            ON f.subitem_id = r.subitem_id INNER JOIN [t_qti_evaluationmaterial] i 
            ON i.flowmaterial_id = f.flowmaterial_id 
                where i.flowmaterial_id = 1385628 
                and i.position = 1 
                and r.item_evaluation_id = b.item_evaluation_id) = 0 then 'Neither' else '' end

from 

t_qti_evaluation_status a
INNER JOIN t_qti_item_evaluation b
ON a.evaluation_id = b.item_evaluation_id 
INNER JOIN t_qti_evaluation c
ON a.content_id = c.content_id 
INNER JOIN t_qti_content d
ON a.content_id = d.content_id
INNER JOIN t_qti_response e
ON b.response_id = e.response_id
INNER JOIN t_qti_evaluationflowmaterial f
ON f.subitem_id = b.subitem_id
INNER JOIN t_qti_evaluationmaterial i
ON i.flowmaterial_id = f.flowmaterial_id
INNER JOIN person p
ON a.candidate_id = p.person_id
```

So the only thing that changes is whether the response is a 1, 2, 3, 4, or 0 (the values I associated to the response in the feedback form). Also, some alterations need to be made to include more "i.flowmaterial_id" which is why the code fails (too many characters)

As you can see, very repetitive, so I created this (which works in SQL but not in the LMS):

```
declare @test varchar(100) = (select e.response_value
    from 
        t_qti_item_evaluation r INNER JOIN t_qti_response e
            ON r.response_id = e.response_id INNER JOIN t_qti_evaluationflowmaterial f
            ON f.subitem_id = r.subitem_id INNER JOIN [t_qti_evaluationmaterial] i
            ON i.flowmaterial_id = f.flowmaterial_id
    where 
        i.position = 1 and i.flowmaterial_id = 1246978 
--connects to the outer query
--and r.item_evaluation_id = b.item_evaluation_id
        ), 

        @result varchar(100)

    select @result =     CASE  @test 
            WHEN  1 THEN 'Highly Satisfied'   
            WHEN  2 THEN 'Satisfied'
            WHEN  3 THEN 'Dissatisfied' 
            WHEN  4 THEN 'Highly Dissatisfied'
            WHEN  0 THEN 'Neither' 
        END    

        print @result
```

The problem with this is that the LMS will ONLY take a select statement as an input, it is not something that you can just dump code and it runs it.

So what I am asking is, is it possible to improve the code a lot so that I am able to add more IDs, or somehow get the 2nd code within a select statement so that it can be put in the LMS.

Not sure what SQL version the LMS is using, but I am testing in SQL 2014

Sorry for the extended question, it is just specific.

Comment: If you need to join it to the main query, you could use an apply. e.g. `select case x.response_value when 1 then 'Highly Satisfied' when 2 then 'Satisfied' etc end from [all my other joins] outer apply (select e.response_value...) x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the other form of the `case`:

```
(case (select e.response_value 
       from t_qti_item_evaluation r INNER JOIN t_qti_response e 
            ON r.response_id = e.response_id INNER JOIN t_qti_evaluationflowmaterial f 
            ON f.subitem_id = r.subitem_id INNER JOIN [t_qti_evaluationmaterial] i 
            ON i.flowmaterial_id = f.flowmaterial_id 
       where i.flowmaterial_id = 1385628 and
             i.position = 1 and
             r.item_evaluation_id = b.item_evaluation_id
      )
      when 1 then 'Highly Satisfied' 
      when 2 then 'Satisfied' 
      when 3 then 'Disatisfied' 
      when 4 then 'Highly Disatisfied' 
      when 0 then 'Neither'
      else ''
 end)
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for that, works very well. (just removed the " =1 ")